# How to config DoctrineMongoDBBundle in symfony 4.0

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine, symfony-3.3, symfony4

I am trying to use `DoctrineMongoDBBundle` in **Symfony 4.0**. The only documentation I can find [is for **Symfony 3**](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html).

**Symfony 4** has no `parameters.yml` or `config.yml`.

How can I configure **Symfony 4.0** to make the `DoctrineMongoDBBundle` work?

Answer (score 1):

@jmleroux's suggestion is right

To install the DoctrineMongoDBBundle in symfony 4.0 + php7.2.1, some extra steps should be done.

1. add following to composer.json

   - **"alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter":
   - "^1.1",    "doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "^3.0",
   - "doctrine/mongodb-odm": "^1.2.0",**

please note, "alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter": "^1.1" is only required if you are using php7

2. update the composer, make sure no error occurs
3. add **use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;** to
   yourcontroller and extend your own controller from **controller**
4. do what @jmleroux suggested

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps I followed to run it on a debian system.

## Setting up php

```
apt-get update && apt-get install --assume-yes wget gnupg gnupg2

apt -y install lsb-release apt-transport-https ca-certificates
wget https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
apt-key add apt.gpg
echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php7.4.list
apt-get update
apt-get install -y php7.2 php7.2-cli php7.2-common php7.2-dev php7.2-mysqli php7.2-xml php7.2-mbstring
```

## Setting up pecl for installing mongodb driver

```
apt-get install -y php-pear
```

## Installing mongodb driver

```
pecl install mongodb
```

## Adding mongodb extension to php config file

```
echo "extension=mongodb.so" >> /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
```

## Add the dependencies to composer.json

```
"alcaeus/mongo-php-adapter": "^1.1",
"doctrine/mongodb-odm-bundle": "^3.0",
"doctrine/mongodb-odm": "^1.2.0"
```

## Add the doctrine_mongodb configuration to config/packages/doctrine.yaml

```
doctrine_mongodb:
    default_commit_options: ~
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
    auto_generate_hydrator_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
    connections:
        default:
            server: '%env(MONGODB_URL)%'
            options: 
                username: '%env(MONGODB_USERNAME)%'
                password: '%env(MONGODB_PASSWORD)%'
    default_database: '%env(MONGODB_DB)%'
    document_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping: true
            mappings:
                App:
                    is_bundle: false
                    type: annotation
                    dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Document'
                    prefix: App\Document\
                    alias: App
```

## Add mongodb connection config to .env file

```
MONGODB_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017
MONGODB_DB=databasename
MONGODB_USERNAME=username
MONGODB_PASSWORD=password
```

## Add the Doctrine MongoDb Bundle to config/bundles.php

```
Doctrine\Bundle\MongoDBBundle\DoctrineMongoDBBundle::class => ['all' => true],
```

## Final Step

```
composer update && composer install
```

Answer (score 0):

The specific MongoDB configuration should now be in a dedicated file in `config/packages` and have the same content than the SF3 `app/config/config.yml`.

For the `mongodb_server` parameter, you could set it in the `config/services.yml` under the `parameters` section, but the best is to use an environment variable like [Doctrine configuration](https://github.com/symfony/demo/blob/master/config/packages/doctrine.yaml#L13).